# SQLite SELECT except where single column has duplicate

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

How can I ensure that s.user_id and w.stage_id do not have duplicate rows? You can see in the screengrab that user_id 117 occurs in two rows. I want to prevent this - perhaps by only including the latest submission in the query?

My returned data is as follows:

[image: sql query]

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.breakout_id, r.case_id, r.stage_id, r.chart_id, s.stage1_choice,s.user_id,w.stage1,w.user_id
FROM Results as r, Submissions as s, Switch as w
WHERE r.breakout_id = '1' AND s.breakout_id = '1' AND w.breakout_id = '1' AND s.user_id = w.user_id AND w.case_id = r.case_id AND s.case_id = r.case_id AND s.stage1_choice IS NOT NULL ORDER BY w.user_id
```

Comment: "Duplicate" rows have different `stage1` field. What row should be left?

Comment: I only want to include the latest entry and ignore the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.breakout_id, r.case_id, r.stage_id, r.chart_id, 
s.stage1_choice,s.user_id,max(w.stage1),w.user_id
FROM Results as r, Submissions as s, Switch as w
WHERE r.breakout_id = '1' AND s.breakout_id = '1' AND w.breakout_id = '1' AND s.user_id = w.user_id 
AND w.case_id = r.case_id AND s.case_id = r.case_id AND 
s.stage1_choice IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY r.breakout_id, r.case_id, r.stage_id, r.chart_id, 
s.stage1_choice,s.user_id,w.user_id
ORDER BY w.user_id;
```